# How can I check if 2 given stacks has the same values? (Not necessarily in the same order)

Tags: java, stack

everybody.
How can I check if 2 stacks has the same values?

For example, in stack1 I have [1,3,4,5] and in stack2 I have [4,3,1,5], so the stacks has the same values and the methood needs to return true.

**In addition, the stacks must be (in the end) as they were given (with the original values and the same order).**

I have started to work on it but unfortuantely it's not working good:

```
import java.util.Stack;
public class StackMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Stack<Integer> st1 = new Stack<Integer>();
        st1.push(2);
        st1.push(643);
        st1.push(254);
        st1.push(13);
        st1.push(74);
        st1.push(6);
        st1.push(5);
        st1.push(99);
        
        Stack<Integer> st2 = new Stack<Integer>();
        st2.push(643);
        st2.push(2);
        st2.push(254);
        st2.push(13);
        st2.push(99);
        st2.push(5);
        st2.push(6);
        st2.push(74);
        System.out.println(isSameStacks(st1,st2));
    }
    public static boolean isSameStacks(Stack st1, Stack st2)
    {
        Stack st1Reverse = new Stack();
        Stack st2Reverse = new Stack();
        boolean isExist = false;
        while(st1.isEmpty()==false)
        {
            isExist = false;
            st1Reverse.push(st1.pop());
            while(st2.isEmpty()==false)
            {
                st2Reverse.push(st2.pop());
                if(st1Reverse.peek()== st2Reverse.peek())
                    isExist  = true;
            }
            while(st2Reverse.isEmpty()==false)
                st2.push(st2Reverse.pop());
            if(isExist!=true)
            {
                while(st1Reverse.isEmpty()==false)
                    st1.push(st1Reverse.pop());
                return false;
            }
        }
        while(st1Reverse.isEmpty()==false)
            st1.push(st1Reverse.pop());
        return true;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way is to use the `Collection` functionality:

```
   public static boolean isSameStacks(Stack st1, Stack st2)   {
        if(st1.size() != st1.size()) return false;
        List list = new ArrayList<>(st1);//add all st1 elements 
        list.removeAll(st2);//remove all st2 elements 
        return list.size() == 0;
   }
```

For completeness here is another solution using `Collection` functionality. It is based on the [partial solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70548419/3992939) posted by @user7:

```
  public static boolean isSameStacks(Stack st1, Stack st2)   {
       return st1.size() == st1.size() &&  
                    new HashSet<>(st1).equals(new HashSet<>(st2)); 
   }
```

Comment: I think it's the best and the easiest way, thank you.:)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**
As mentioned by @lzruo, if the stack has duplicate elements, this will not work. Say stack1 has `[1, 1, 2]` and stack2 has `[1, 2]`, this will return true.

**Initial answer:**
Since a Java `Stack` is a `Vector` which is a `Collection` (specifically a `List`), we can iterate or create a stream from the stack and collect it in a `Set` (`HashSet`). This will not affect the elements (will not be removed). in the stack or their ordering.

Or simply, since a `HashSet` constructor accepts a `Collection` as we do like:

```
Set<Integer> stack1AsSet = new HashSet<>(st1);
Set<Integer> stack2AsSet = new HashSet<>(st2);

System.out.println(stack1AsSet.equals(stack2AsSet)); //prints true
```

The stack order or elements would not be affected.

```
System.out.println(st1.pop()); //prints 99
```

---

The answer by @c0der is simpler. But if you use a HashSet, you can check the stack sizes are equal before checking the set contents.

```
return st1.size() == st1.size() &&  new HashSet<>(st1).equals(new HashSet<>(st2));
```

Comment: Note: While this works for the given data, it will give false positives, if one of the input stacks has duplicate elements.

Comment: @Izruo good point. To overcome it I would suggest nice and concise `return st1.size() == st1.size() &&  new HashSet<>(st1).equals(new HashSet<>(st2));`

Comment: @lzruo Good point. I'll update the answer

Comment: @user7 _The answer by lzruo is simpler_ there is no answer by lzuro. I suggest you implement the change I proposed.

Comment: @c0der. Ah I meant you. I had the wrong username copied. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

We can use Hashmap to get track of the element count in each stack and use them to check if both the stack were same

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Stack<Integer> st1 = new Stack<Integer>();
        st1.push(2);
        st1.push(643);
        st1.push(254);
        st1.push(13);
        st1.push(74);
        st1.push(6);
        st1.push(5);
        st1.push(99);
        
        Stack<Integer> st2 = new Stack<Integer>();
        st2.push(643);
        st2.push(2);
        st2.push(254);
        st2.push(13);
        st2.push(99);
        st2.push(5);
        st2.push(6);
        st2.push(74);
        System.out.println("Is Same STack: " + isSameStacks(st1,st2));
    }
    public static boolean isSameStacks(Stack<Integer> st1, Stack<Integer> st2)
    {
        Stack<Integer> st1Reverse = new Stack<Integer>();
        Stack<Integer> st2Reverse = new Stack<Integer>();
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        boolean isExist = false;
        while(st1.isEmpty()==false)
        {
            isExist = false;
            Integer val = st1.pop();
            Integer val2 = st2.pop();
            st1Reverse.push(val);
            st2Reverse.push(val2);
            if(map.get(val) == null) {
                map.put(val, 0);
            }
            if(map.get(val2) == null) {
                map.put(val2, 0);
            }
            map.put(val, map.get(val) + 1);
            map.put(val2, map.get(val2) + 1);
        }
        boolean res = true;
        Integer tmp;
        while(st1Reverse.isEmpty()==false) {
            tmp = st1Reverse.pop();
            if(map.get(tmp)%2 != 0) {
                res = false;
            }
            st1.push(tmp);
        }
        while(st2Reverse.isEmpty()==false) {
            tmp = st2Reverse.pop();
            if(map.get(tmp)%2 != 0) {
                res = false;
            }
            st2.push(tmp);
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I learned some new things from your explanation 

Comment: This can fail if the stacks are of different sizes and one stack or both have duplicate values.  Also, this is can be simplified.  There is no need to copy st1 and st2. You can simply iterate over them. Instead of iterating over two stacks `st1Reverse` and `st2Reverse`  iterate over `map` and check that all are even.

Comment: To make it work on stacks with different sizes and stacks having duplicate values, we can use a hashmap for each of the stacks.  before iterating, we can check the size of two stacks.  if they were not equal, then, it will not be the same.  If both stacks have the same size, then we can iterate through the stack and increment the value of hashmap.  while checking, we need to decrement the values and check if the value is less than 0.  if it is, then the two stacks were not the same